# Implementing and() method for ee.Image in Google Earth Engine Python API

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-python-api, geemap, syntaxerror

I am struggling to implement Google Earth Engine's `and` method in the Python API. I have two binary images (one called gfm and one called hf) and would like to find the union of them.

In the GEE Javascript API, this is fairly simple.

```
var union = gfm.and(hf)
```

In Python, I try to run the following code

```
union = gfm.and(hf)
```

but get the following error: SyntaxError: invalid syntax, as shown in the image below

[image: error image]

Comment: I have used `and()` without issues, perhaps there is a difference in the previous lines. Did you try `(ee.Image(gfm)).and(ee.Image(hf))`?

Answer (score 1):

Use `And` instead.

```py
union = gfm.And(hf)
```

`and` is a reserved operator in Python (so are `or` and `not`), so it was renamed with an uppercase first letter.

Comment: Thank you very much!